# Springboot no lee mi HTML

Tags: java, html, netbeans, spring, spring-boot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy siguiendo un tutorial en Udemy y el instructor ya no sabe como se generó mi error y que por alguna razón, la IDE(Netbeans) no estaría leyendo las librerias de Springboot.

Es un proyecto inicializado en Spring y Java con el objetivo de ser una Ecommerce, por ahora solo estoy en la parte en que se conectan el `main` con el `controller` y cuando se ejecuta la app, se desplegaría el `.html` en http://localhost:8080/

En realidad pasa esto:
[image: home]

Clases:
**main**

```
        package com.proyectoSpring.tricko;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.proyectoSpring.controller"})
    public class TrickoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(TrickoApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

**controller**

```
package com.proyectoSpring.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ListadoController {

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "listado";
    }

}
```

**html**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <!-- Required meta tags -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

            <!-- CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ibarra+Real+Nova:400,600i|Noto+Sans+TC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">


            <title>Tienda Tricko Design</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/img/trickologo.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">Bienvenidos!</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Envíos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Formatos
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Impresiones</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Digitales</a>
                            </div>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="img/01.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Terror Series</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Clown & Zombies.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="img/03.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Terror Series</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Hands.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="img/06.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Terror Series</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Hands.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="img/07.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Terror Series</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Monstruos.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                            <img src="img/08.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Terror Series</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">Miedo.</p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: agregaste el sufijo ".html" a el bean del ViewResolver? Si no te regresara tal cual una cadena como lo esta haciendo,checa este ejemplo: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-view-resolver-example/

Comment: No sé por qué pero no tengo ese xml, solo un POM del Springboot. Igualmente gracias porque ya sé como se llama esa conexión!

Answer (score 1):

En **Spring** tienes las anotaciones **@Controller** y **@RestController**. Este último, realmente es la combinación de las etiquetas **@Controller** y **@ResponseBody**.

Como observarás la única diferencia entre ambos es una etiquete adicional. El **@Responsebody** hace que la salida  que se retorne desde el controlador se escriba directamente en el cuerpo de respuesta.

Por tal razón, cuando pruebas tu programa te sale el nombre de la vista y no el HTML de tu archivo. El **@RestController** generalmente cuando quieres proporcionar servicios web.

Para que tu vista se procese debes cambiar la anotación por @Controller de forma tal que lo que retornes se pasará a los controladores de vista.

Comment: Me sale un **_whitelabel error page_**:
**"
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [listado], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [listado], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"**

Comment: El archivo listado.html está dentro del directorio templates?

Comment: Sí, en **_src/main/resources/static/templates_**

Comment: Como ejecutas la aplicación con el servidor spring? Puedes mostrarme el Application.properries? He observado que tu html no tiene ninguna referencia a thymeleaf. El directorio es **resources/templates**

Comment: En Netbeans, click en el proyecto y _Run_. Mi application.properties está vacío, pensé que era normal eso pero vi otros proyectos que tienen varias líneas ahí, por eso no comprendo. Solo tengo un _pom_ pero es de el springboot con sus plugins.

Comment: Pero si tu directorio **templates** esta bajo **static** eso esta mal. Verifica que tienes **/src/main/resources/templates/listado.html**

Comment: Lo moví dentro de esa carpeta y sigue apareciendome _**TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [listado], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers_** Aunque en Netbeans me aparece dentro de un directorio llamado _**Other Sources**_

Comment: Puedes mostrarme la estructura de carpetas que tienes?

Comment: Ya añadí screen de los directorios

Comment: Mira, parece que está bien. Lo único, aunque es mas una recomendación es que sigas las buenas practicas del spring donde el paquete donde está la clase principal TrickoApplication.java (com.proyectoSpring.tricko) debería ser el paquete raíz de toda tu aplicación, de lo contrario, vas a tener que ir agregándolos al ComponetScan. Lo que sí observo es que estás utilizando JDK13 y no sé si spring ya soporta ese jdk. Quizá probando con una versión anterior. Cuando ejecuta no sale ningún error o mensaje en la consola?

Comment: La consola ejecuta normalmente pero sale lo mismo que en `localhost:8080` sí, los que adjunté en todo el post. Estoy por instalar otro jdk, según veo en el tutorial que sigo, usa jdk 12 y funciona lo más bien, todo el proyecto está exactamente igual hasta los directorios... Raro. Una pregunta, ¿Qué serían "buenas practicas de Spring"?

Comment: Dale una mirada a https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-build-systems.

Comment: Pude solucionar la conexión del thymeleaf, gracias a este post : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944355/error-resolving-template-index-template-might-not-exist-or-might-not-be-acces]

Comment: Que bueno. Bueno el problema fue consecuencia de solucionar el problema de este Post ya que te trabajaba . RestControllers donde no iinterviene el thymeleaf . Deberias  editar la pregunta ( si se puede) para agregar este último problema y luego registras la solucio y tu mismo l das como solucionado.. En todo caso, déjala como resuelta y registras el problema y la solución. Si es que puedes porque queda como media incompleta.